# Is there Pause action For Download Manager in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I'm using download manager class in android to download some files .
This class can add and remove a request of downloading .

Is there any way to pause a specific download then resume it ?

Or Is there another way to do that ?

Edit:
I found this way, It's working:

- When pause downloading process, close the file we wrote on.
- When resume downloading, access to the file (not completed) and get its size
- Add downloaded bytes info to the header of httpRequest :  mHttpRequset.setHeader("Range",  "bytes=" + mPreviouslyDownloadedBytes + "-");
- mHttpClient.execute(mHttpRequset);

Comment: Hi, please give me your java code for Pause/Resume methods, i want found a way that while using android.app.downloadmanager we have pause/resume ability but every solution i found on web, they write new download manager, until i see your edited post.

Comment: Please see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860322/how-to-pause-resume-downloads-in-android-programming?noredirect=1#comment45987539_28860322

Comment: In my solution I've used a custom way, using HttpClient class, I didn't use the native DownloadManager class because it's not extensible.

Comment: post it as an answer so it goeson unanswered