# Android : How to pause and resume using DownloadManager?

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager, download-manager

this is my code and i want to add resumable feature but i couldn't is it posible?

```java
downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/20MB.zip");
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);

//Restrict the types of networks over which this download may proceed.
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
//Set whether this download may proceed over a roaming connection.
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
//Set the title of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled).
request.setTitle("My Data Download");
//Set a description of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled)
request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.");
//Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"20MB.zip");

//Enqueue a new download and same the referenceId
downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to implement Pause/Resume functionality using the following implementation via the Android DownloadManager and Downloads Content Provider:

```
private boolean resumeDownload(Context context, String downloadTitle) {
    int updatedRows = 0;        

    ContentValues resumeDownload = new ContentValues();
    resumeDownload.put("control", 0); // Resume Control Value

    try {
        updatedRows = context
            .getContentResolver()
            .update(Uri.parse("content://downloads/my_downloads"),
                resumeDownload,
                "title=?",
                new String[]{ downloadTitle });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to update control for downloading video");
    }

    return 0 < updatedRows;
}

private boolean pauseDownload(Context context, String downloadTitle) {
    int updatedRows = 0;

    ContentValues pauseDownload = new ContentValues();
    pauseDownload.put("control", 1); // Pause Control Value

    try {
        updatedRows = context
            .getContentResolver()
            .update(Uri.parse("content://downloads/my_downloads"),
                pauseDownload,
                "title=?",
                new String[]{ downloadTitle });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to update control for downloading video");
    }

    return 0 < updatedRows;
}
```

Comment: witch url is your mean?

Comment: Interesting variant. However, I am afraid that it will be applied for ALL downloads events.

Comment: hi, @jjh can you please help me to in resume download.

Comment: pause is working fine but resume not working. can you please help ?